# How do I set up an Angular 8 app that has a node backend and host it on firebase?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I want to build a web scraper using node and send that data to my angular front end. I want to host this PWA on firebase since its free and easy to use.

This is my first time putting node and angular together. 
When researching firebase hosting, i noticed there was a particular structure in order to use cloud functions. I can't seem to find a basic example of this on google, can anyone show me a very basic set up of this?

**Ultimately I would like to do the following:**

- Use node to scape data from the web
- angular front end to display the returned data
- and eventually store that data to firebase
- be hosted on firebase (or a better alternative)

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions-angular/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write your backend code using node.js and express now deploy the code in fire base functions(only calls related to the google services like firestore,youtube.. only works as free of cost.)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

if you want to use mongodb like that then better deploy your code in heroku.com

now build your UI using angular and finally when it is ready to deploy

do production build **(ng build --prod)**

now you will get a **dist** folder

you can deploy this in any hosting services not only in firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting

firebase is only free when you completely depend on firebase in the backend!